# Stack array variables not consistent C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, stack

The following program produces strange behavior:
makefile

```
all:
    gcc main.c -o main;
```

build example

```
./main 3 5 6 9
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "insertion(): requires a list of numbers\n");
            exit(1);
    } else if (argc - 1 > INT_MAX) {
            fprintf(stderr, "insertion(): requires a list of numbers less than INT_MAX\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    int ints[argc - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            char ci = *argv[i];
            int i = ci - '0';
            ints[i - 1] = i;
            printf("%d\n", ints[i - 1]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < argc - 1; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", ints[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
3
5
6
9
random stack stuff
random stack stuff
random stack stuff
random stack stuff
```

There must be a concept I am missing here?
Edit: Working solution thanks @tilz0R, @dbush

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "insertion(): requires a list of numbers\n");
            exit(1);
    } else if (argc - 1 > INT_MAX) {
            fprintf(stderr, "insertion(): requires a list of numbers less than INT_MAX\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    int ints[argc - 1];
    int k;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            char ci = *argv[i];
            k = ci - '0';
            ints[i - 1] = k;
            printf("%d\n", ints[i - 1]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < argc - 1; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", ints[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argc + 1 > INT_MAX` ? Two `i` in different scopes.

Comment: Also note it’s extremely unlikely that `INT_MAX` is 99999999999

Comment: @John3136 You did mean to quote the expression  `argc - 1 > INT_MAX)`, didn't you? To the OP: hard to see how an int can ever be greater than the maximum int.

Comment: @John3136 yes I did

Comment: I know it was a quick comment because I knew someone would answer the question pretty quick (2 `i`s), but `argc + 1 > INT_MAX` ? I thought by pointing it out the OP might read it and think "How can an int be > INT_MAX? Does that argc + 1 somehow change type? Not sure, perhaps I'll play it safe or go and do some research to check..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `int i;` inside first `for` twice under different scope.

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    char ci = *argv[i];
    int i = ci - '0'; // <--- this is problematic
    ints[i - 1] = i;  // <--- this is problematic 
    printf("%d\n", ints[i - 1]);
}
```

Better would be

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    char ci = *argv[i];
    int tmp = ci - '0';
    ints[i - 1] = tmp;
    printf("%d\n", ints[i - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at this loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        char ci = *argv[i];
        int i = ci - '0';
        ints[i - 1] = i;
        printf("%d\n", ints[i - 1]);
}
```

You define `i` as your loop control variable.  But then you define *another* variable named `i` inside of the loop.  This shadows the `i` defined at the start of the loop.

Looking at these lines:

```
int i = ci - '0';
ints[i - 1] = i;
```

On the first iteration of the loop, you read the value `'3'`.  That is stored in the new `i`.  Then the second line becomes:

```
ints[3 - 1] = 3;
```

Later iterations effective do this:

```
ints[5 - 1] = 5;
ints[6 - 1] = 6;
ints[9 - 1] = 9;
```

So you never write to the first two elements of the array, and you write past the end of the array 3 times.  Writing past the end of an array, as well as reading uninitialized elements, invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Give the inner `i` a different name (ex. `value`).  This prevents the outer `i` from being masked.

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        char ci = *argv[i];
        int value = ci - '0';
        ints[i - 1] = value;
        printf("%d\n", ints[i - 1]);
}
```